# Объявление процедуры принимающей название базы

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `getOldPrivateArticles`(`db` varchar,`contest_id` int)
begin

select 
        article_id as id, 
        contest_id, 
        if(science_id = 0, 1, science_id) as category_id,
        user_id as user_id,
        status_id as status_id,
        article_name_ru as name,
        last_status_time as updated_at

from `db`.pp_articles

where status_id != 3

end;;
```

При сохранении выдает ошибку. Ничего конкретного - просто синтаксическая ошибка, даже без указания строки. Что не так?

Comment: Так не получится. Используйте Prepared Statement.

Comment: @Akina это еще что такое? О_о

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @Akina ага, т.е. запрос строкой и подстановка параметров... А есть возможность как-то этот запрос отдельно записать? Ну просто он вон не маленький и лепить его в одну строку будет не читабельно.

Comment: Так вроде в MySQL не запрещено закрывать кавычки не в той строке где вы их открыли ...

Comment: @Akina Не выходит так https://pastebin.com/Nbax3FsR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?.pp_articles

Comment: @DarkByte Ну-ну... прочитал, но ни фига не понял... Какая в пень подстановка параметров? Читай ещё раз. Имя таблицы - литерал, и не может быть параметром! Подставлять значения надо непосредственно в строковой переменной с текстом запроса, а не как параметр в EXECUTE.

Comment: @Akina ну а зачем тогда было это советовать если так не проканает? :( И мне не имя таблицы, а имя базы надо подставить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getOldPrivateArticles (db varchar(16), contest_id int)
BEGIN
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT article_id AS id, 
                           ', contest_id, ' AS contest_id, 
                           IF(science_id = 0, 1, science_id) AS category_id, 
                           user_id AS user_id, 
                           status_id AS status_id, 
                           article_name_ru AS name, 
                           last_status_time AS updated_at 
                    FROM ', db, '.pp_articles 
                    WHERE status_id != 3');
/* SELECT @sql; */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: Не создается. Видит ошибку на строке присвоения.

Comment: Текст ошибки - секрет?

Comment: Да просто опять ничего конкретного: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' contest_id int)

Comment: @DarkByte *near ' contest_id int)* Там точно обычный пробел? перенабери первую строку заново, а не копипастом.

Comment: Перенабрал все заново. Кстати такой способ присвоения мой mysql кажется не поддерживает. Только через set (пробовал отдельно). Да и врятли разумно называть переменную sql - там вроде есть такое ключевое слово. Но тем не менее не прокатывает... http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110418/24HNJC7O

Comment: *Только через set* Да, упустил... добавлю. *врятли разумно называть переменную sql* всю жисть так называю. *вроде есть такое ключевое слово* Символ '@' снимает любые проблемы такого рода. *не прокатывает* После SET сделай вместо выполнения простое `SELECT @sql;` и покажи результат вывода.

Comment: Нет. Та же ошибка. Похоже проблема именно в строке с конкатенацией. Но что за проблема - хз... Если просто сделать вот так http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110418/S9JHMu5B то все работает. Значит похоже дело в переменных... Может он не умеет автоматически конвертировать int в строку? Как это вручную сделать?

Comment: Хотя нет вот так тоже работает http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110418/ftdaXQ2k В общем что-то странное творится...

Comment: *Похоже проблема именно в строке с конкатенацией.* Скриншот показывает, что проблем с конкатенацией НЕТ. Она нормально выполнена, и в переменную помещён результирующий текст запроса.  Вот только его весь не видно, а по начальному куску нельзя сказать, верен он синтаксически или нет.

Comment: Да все там верно... http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110418/nWGUTxrX Я просто не думал что вам особо интересно что там выведет. Важно то что вывело без ошибок... Проблема именно в процедуре возникает (даже с закомментированным prepare блоком). А вот что с ней не так я не понимаю...

Comment: ООО!!! Кажется я понял в чем проблема. Переменной db надо было задать размер. Например varchar(10). Правда дело хоть и сдвинулось с мертвого места, но все-же еще не заработало... Теперь ошибка уже на выполнении prepare http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110418/PJAVHagU

Comment: Внёс изменения в текст. Пробуй.

Comment: И еще у меня возникло внезапно страшное подозрение... А процедуры вообще можно селектить? Я имею ввиду то что мне надо использовать результат процедуры в запросе. Т.е. мне нужна фактически вьюха, только с параметрами. Так вот у меня не получается использовать ее результат (ну не ее, я тестил на другой процедуре) select * from call myproc(123, 'test') - не канает :(

Comment: *А процедуры вообще можно селектить?* Процедуру можно выполнить. И обращаться к результату как будто это обычный SELECT. *select call myproc(123, 'test') - не канает* Просто `call myproc(123, 'test')`. А в выходной набор попадёт результат того SELECT, который внутри процедуры.

Comment: Но мне надо использовать результат!!! Т.е. ту таблицу которая вернется из процедуры.

Comment: Где именно? Как именно? *таблицу которая вернется из процедуры* Из процедуры возвращается не таблица, а набор записей. Если его надо использовать где-то ещё, следует поместить выбранные записи во временную таблицу, и её использовать в других запросах.

Comment: Я же показал пример select * from call myproc(123). На самом деле передо мной стоит задача смержить десяток баз данных с одинаковой структурой в одну. Я делаю это с помощью операции union потаблично. Но мне не хочется прописывать каждый раз весь select (баз то много). Ради этого я и затеял всю эту фигню с подстановкой имени базы.

Comment: Ну в таком случае слив подготовленных данных во временную таблицу - самое оно.

Comment: Какая еще временная таблица. Мне вьюха нужна!!! Я делаю вьюху!!! Это важно! Данные могут поменяться.